# How I can use feature layer DefinitionExpression dynamically by using the javascript API 3.17?

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

My Flow is like below:

1. When area name are selected from the dropdown, the map layer is filtered by using DefinitionExpression of feature layer.

   layer.setDefinitionExpression('area_name = xyz');
2. Till that this is working perfectly but there are no any layer refreshment by applying setDefinitionExpression second time. It mean that there are no any action happened after selecting area from dropdown second time.

Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

It would help to see your code...

You could listen for a change in your dropdown with jquery and execute a function on each change:

```py
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#DropDownID").on("change", function(e) {
        someFunction($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Then change the definition expression

```py
function someFunction(defExp) {     
    if (defExp === 'x') {
        layer.setDefinitionExpression('area_name = x');
    }
    else if (defExp === 'y') {
        layer.setDefinitionExpression('area_name = y');
    }
    else if (defExp === 'z') {
        layer.setDefinitionExpression('area_name = z');
    }
}
```

[jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/cadica/edit?html,js,output)